# PHP XML or Json Choices on webpage

Tags: php, xml, json

I am using the get parameters so the user can choose XML output or Json.
Upon their choice it either runs a json function or a xml function, on the same page.
However, despite my efforts, even though the code is never told to enter the XML function while json is selected, it still runs the **header("Content-type: text/xml");** within the XML function. It does not run anything else.
The problem is when it attempts to write:

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s" ) . "GMT"); 
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

In the json function, it gives me an error that the header has already been altered (even though I never executed the XML function.
I had to remedy that by making a separate webpage, one for json and one for xml. However, I would like them to goto the same URL and grab the gets to select if they want json or XML without any errors.
Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: We would probably need to see your full code, rather than just the `header` calls but usually you will get an error if you attempt to output content before a `header` method call. Eg. the xml content before the JSON headers

Comment: You need to provide the exact error message you get. I somehow assume that the error you tell you get is not the real error. Please double check.

Answer (score 0):

check the documentation on header. you may have to set

```
header("Content-type: application/json", true);
                                         ####
```

to make sure your new content-type header replaces the *Content-type* header that may have already been set. http://php.net/header

Comment: I do not think this is the case here, but made it more clear what I think you wanted to say. (sent headers can't be changed any longer)